# SSL instead SAML

Tags: authentication, ssl, saml

I don't understand why we don't use just SSL instead the SAML protocol, that's because SSL is not sufficient? SSL encrypt all communications (authentification information also) between idP and SP but why we need SAML ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8859120/372643

Comment: Agree with @Bruno - just to add that SAML provides federation i.e. the ability to connect with an external application using your local credentials.